# expand image with link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm really new to javascript, and I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want to have an image expand by clicking a link--the codes I've seen have the user click the image itself expanded it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are clearly expecting someone to do this for you without any effort on your part. -1

Comment: I'm sorry for seeming that way. I just didn't even know if something like this was possible.

Comment: It's fine starting a question with "I want", as long as you at least explain what you have done/tried on your own already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<img src="yourImage.png" alt="image" class="small" id="img"/>

<a href="#" id="btnExpand">Expand</a>
<a href="#" id="btnRevert">Revert</a>
```

**CSS**

```
img.small {
  width: 48px;
}
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('btnExpand').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('img').className = '';
});

document.getElementById('btnRevert').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('img').className = 'small';
});
```

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/MYWygG).

Comment: I'm really new to javascript and this seems easy enough for my purposes. Thank you! I'll go try this out.

Comment: I suppose that you are new in JS so I try to do an easy example. There are fancy ways to do achieve your requirement and get better results but I think that this example is easy to start.

Comment: @Christy if it works please accept the answer, if not feel free to ask.